# Buscar todas las etiquetas que empiezen por una cadena determinada

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estoy haciendo un scrapy para una página donde busco una etiqueta. Lo hago con BeautifulSoup.
Busco todos los enlaces que empiezan con las mismas, pero terminan de forma diferente.

**Ejemplo:**

```
for url in soup.find_all('a', href=("/es/nds/*******")):
```

Donde los asteriscos representan que busco un final de cadena cualquiera.
No sé como buscarlo. He probado:

```
 href=("/es/nds/"+""), href=("/es/nds/\*") y similares.
```

¿Podéis echarme una mano con ello?

Gracias.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<a href="/es/nds/\*">foo</a> 
<a href="/es/nds/aaa/bbb">foo</a> 
<a href="/es/ccc">foo</a> 
<a href="/gggg/ffff">foo</a> 
<a href="/es/nds/_hhhh">foo</a> 
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
patt = re.compile('^/es/nds/')
for url in soup.find_all('a', href=patt):
    print(url)
```

La salida es :

```
<a href="/es/nds/\*">foo</a>
<a href="/es/nds/aaa/bbb">foo</a>
<a href="/es/nds/_hhhh">foo</a>
```

En este caso simplemente se usa el carácter especial `^` (Caret) que indica que el patrón coincide con el principio de la cadena.

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias FJSevilla

Comment: Hola @Shorosky, no se debe colocar "Solucionado" o similares en el título de la pregunta([¿Es correcto editar el titulo para poner “\[SOLUCIONADO\]”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2508/15089)), el procedimiento en StackOverflow es en todo caso aceptar la respuesta que consideres que mejor soluciona tu problema. Para saber como funciona puedes mirarte [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/15089). Un saludo.